# Save changes to database through DataGridView

Tags: c#, database

Edit:
I tried these new lines. It seems like it just doesn't update. The adapter has the update enabled.

```
DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Voulez-vous enregistrer ?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                ClosureDataDataSet dataSetChanged = (ClosureDataDataSet)closureDataDataSet.GetChanges();
                this.tableTableAdapter.Update(dataSetChanged);
                this.closureDataDataSet.AcceptChanges();
                dgvClosures.Refresh();
```

I can't seam to keep changes to my database when i stop running the program

I created a SQL database locally in Visual Studio C# that I show and update through DataGridView. The changes get saved fine as long as I don't stop running the program. I'd like it to keep those changes from run to run.

Here is what I tried. The DataGridView and the dataset are linked already.

```
DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save ?", "Message", 
MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            this.tableTableAdapter.Update(closureDataDataSet.Table);
            dgvClosures.Refresh();
        }
```

What I want is the data to be saved from use to use. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle `OnFormClosing` event of a form and ask user to save changes before the form or application is closed.

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosing(e);
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save ?", "Message", 
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        this.tableTableAdapter.Update(closureDataDataSet.Table);
        // dgvClosures.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: This saves when closed, but the same issue stays. When re-launching the app, the database has not been updated, it's back to its original state.

Comment: Sounds like you always copy the database file to the output folder when you build the project

Comment: This is how i fill the dqtqgridview private void `SettingsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       
            this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.closureDataDataSet.Table);
        }`

Comment: Do you see your database file in solution explorer? In case yes, please check if there is no "Copy Always" option in Properties window

Comment: It's written 'Not Copy' under the copy in directory

Comment: Ok, looks like we need to see how you work with the database. Please show the code responsible for loading the data

Comment: `private void SettingsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.closureDataDataSet.Table); }`